# UI canvas Index

Tags: c#, android-canvas, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have and script below that does the following:

The player starts with 3 hearts [0] if it suffers damage loses one heart and changes the texture to 2 hearts [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa5xK.png), if he wins one extra heart back to the texture [0] .. If you're having only one heart [ 2] and suffers an injury, the game ends.

This code works perfectly, but I would like to convert it to UI Canvas Image. How do I do this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Hearts : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D[]initialHeart;
    private int hearts;
    private int currentHearts;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        GetComponent<GUITexture>().texture = initialHeart[0];
        hearts = initialHeart.Length;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    public bool TakeHeart()
    {
        if (hearts < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (currentHearts < (hearts - 1)) {
            currentHearts += 1;
            GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [currentHearts];
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public bool AddHeart() {
        if (currentHearts > 0) {
            currentHearts -= 1;
            GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [currentHearts];
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Look what is happening:

In the object inspector, HealthBar I put 3 hearts as image (first imagem attached). But when I go into the script and try to select the images to be changed according to the user's  progress, is not allowed to use image, objects only (second imagem attached).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**.Change `Texture2D` to `Sprite`.

**2**.Then change `GetComponent<GUITexture>().texture = initialHeart[0];` to  `GetComponent<Image>().sprite = initialHeart[0];`

**3**.And the two `GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture = initialHeart [currentHearts];` to  `GetComponent<Image>().sprite = initialHeart[currentHearts];`

**Note**: Doing `GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture` and `GetComponent<Image>().sprite` is not good. If you need to access any component **multiple** times, you need to `cache` it. That means you do `GetComponent<Image>()` once and save it to variable. That variable you can now use many other times. I noticed this in your other questions/codes too and decided it's time to tell you that. Take a look at the code below to understand it more. Code not tested but it compiles.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Hearts : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sprite[] initialHeart;
    private int hearts;
    private int currentHearts;
    // Use this for initialization

    //Used for chaching Image so that you won't be doing GetComponent<Image>(); each time
    Image heartImage;


    void Start()
    {
        //Cache the Image once so that you won't be doing GetComponent<Image>(); each time
        heartImage = GetComponent<Image>();
        heartImage.sprite = initialHeart[0];
        hearts = initialHeart.Length;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public bool TakeHeart()
    {
        if (hearts < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (currentHearts < (hearts - 1))
        {

            currentHearts += 1;
            heartImage.sprite = initialHeart[currentHearts];
            return true;


        }
        else
        {

            return false;

        }
    }



    public bool AddHeart()
    {

        if (currentHearts > 0)
        {
            currentHearts -= 1;
            heartImage.sprite = initialHeart[currentHearts];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I change changed the `initialHeart` from `Image` to `Sprite` so that you can put `Sprite` directly. Don't forget to remove `GUITexture` from the GameObject this script will be attached to. Also make sure that the GameObject you are attaching this script to has an `Image` attached to it. If you don't, `GetComponent<Image>();` will fail.

Comment: Just as note: That `using UnityEngine.UI;` is required for working with UI stuff in code. If you don't copy and get an error on `Image` that would be why.

Comment: @GunnarB that too. I didn't mention that because I showed him a video tutorial about `UI` few days ago and I expect him to know that by now. Thanks for mentioning that just in-case.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the Inspector. I have a UI Image as HelthBar name, Heart script is attached to this UI. I select the Sprite and take the picture with 3 hearts in scrip place Size to 3: but to attach I have to create 3 child of HeartBar, Heartbar1, 2 and 3? And then later attach to the Heart script?

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende You can do this without creating 3 textures. Are 3 all images in one texture?

Comment: I can not attach within the Heart script at inspect the texture! Only accepts objects.

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende Can you put `EDIT` in your question and post a picture of what is not working. Also, you did not answer my last question. Do you have 3 separate images or is it just one image that is sliced in unity?

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende I was expecting you to attach each sprite in GameObject then plug it in to each array in `initialHeart`. You didn't seem to like that. So I changed `initialHeart` from `Image` to `Sprite` and made a little bit modification. Just copy the new code. You should have no problem now. Also if you want to notify me next time, make a comment under this post or I won't know that you updated the post.

Comment: @Programmer again another perfect answer to my problem. Ty soo much!